# Is there any React Native text editor component?

Tags: react-native

I am looking for a text editor component for React Native without WebView. I found only react-native-zss-rich-text-editor, but it uses WebView, which I think is terrible.

I hope to find something, that works with NSAttributedString and SpannableString for IOS and Android in a native way, like in Evernote, for example.

[Evernote Android app text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmtZ.jpg)

Comment: did you have a look at this?! https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: Its just a TextInput, I need a possibility for users to change color, font, make underlines and etc. directly from the app.

Comment: Than this should be a good starting point. You might have to add some functionality yourself, but the `TextInput` provides the baseline.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Mind sharing what you came up with?

Comment: @chapeljuice yes, I've posted my component in answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TextArea component, that wraps TextInput and resizes it automatically, when you press "new line" button

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class TextArea extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        initialHeight: PropTypes.number,
        isEditing: PropTypes.bool,
        scrollViewRef: PropTypes.object,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        initialHeight: 40,
        isEditing: true,
        scrollViewRef: null,
    }

    state = {
        height: this.props.initialHeight,
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._isUnmounted = false
    }

    focus(){
        this.refs.textInput.focus()
    }

    blur(){
        this.refs.textInput.blur()
    }

    _contentSizeChanged = e => {
        this.setState({
            height: e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
        }, () => {
            if (this.props.scrollViewRef) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (!this._isUnmounted) this.props.scrollViewRef.scrollToEnd()
                }, 0)
            }
        })
    }

    _onChangeText = text => {
        this.props.onChangeText(text)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <TextInput
                ref = "textInput"
                multiline
                value = {this.props.text}
                style = {{ height: this.state.height, color: 'black', flex: 1 }}
                onChangeText = {this._onChangeText}
                onContentSizeChange = {this._contentSizeChanged}
                editable = {this.props.isEditing}
                blurOnSubmit = {false}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this really answer your question about implementing a "text editor" though? Did you implement the actual text editing part as well? If so, care to share?

Comment: This is only solution I implemented. I forgot, why I decided not to implement the other parts